# GCC warning on upcasting a float to double

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, type-promotion

Since `math.h` declares both `int isnan(double x)` and `int isnanf(float x)`, I expected the following code, when compiled with `gcc -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wdouble-promotion` to generate some kind of "float to double promotion" warning. However, it does not. Why is this the case?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  float x = 1.23f;
  printf("%s\n", isnan(x) ? "nan" : "number");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `isnan` is calling a function? [Note that these functions are obsolete. C99 defines macros...](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isnanf)

Comment: Adding a `--std=c89` produces something that looks like your desired warning.

Comment: @teapot418 - What magic is happening in the compiler that `-std=c99` does not produce the warning? C does not have the C++ ability to declare the same function name with different argument signatures. So, how can one `isnan()` function operate both on `float` and `double` arguments at the same time?

Comment: @PaulGrinberg the `float` version has an `f` at the end of the name: `isnanf`, while the `double` version does not have that. So, it has different names.

Comment: It's also warning me about implicit declaration of isnan and my math.h has the isnan macro hidden behind an `#ifdef __USE_ISOC99` so C99 is using a macro routing the thing to a builtin and C89 is using an implicit declaration without a prototype that presumably defaults to double.

Comment: Example "compiler magic": https://www.cygwin.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17441

Comment: @teapot418 You may need `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` or `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to fix the implicit declaration.

Comment: You can write the function call as `(isnan)(x)` to bypass the `isnan(x)` macro. Whether or not the compiler will find a declaration of that function depends on the implementation since the function is not part of the C standard (although the `isnan(x)` macro is standard since C99). You may need to define a feature test macro to persuade the compiler to declare it as a function.

Comment: Even when persuading GCC to call an actual function called `isnan`, it still does not seem to warn about the promotion of the argument to `double`. (Using GCC 12.2 on Debian.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since `math.h` declares both `int isnan(double x)` and `int isnanf(float x)`

Does it?  The C language specification documents only an `isnan()` *macro* supporting all floating-point types.  If the implementation provides an `isnan()` function accepting an argument of type `double` then I expect that to be shadowed by the macro in a conforming implementation.

> I expected the following code, when compiled with `gcc -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wdouble-promotion` to generate some kind of "float to double promotion" warning. However, it does not. Why is this the case?

Because the `isnan()` macro supports all floating-point types, and your particular one does it without a conversion that would elicit such a warning.  Here's a plausible implementation as a type-generic macro:

```
#define isnan(x) _Generic((x), \
    long double: isnanl,       \
    default: isnan,            \
    float: isnanf              \
)(x)
```

(That assumes that the designated functions are available, including `isnan(double)`, though C does not require that.)

Generic selection and the ability to define type-generic macros was new in C11.  Therefore, if you select a strict-conformance mode for an earlier version of the standard then it would not be surprising to get a version that actually does perform some kind of conversion.

Comment: FWIW, the spec has *never* required (or even mentioned) the traditional `isnan()` function.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott. I have revised this answer to avoid making contra-factual claims about `isnan()`.